ggplot bar chart position = "identity" overlaying values with same number in wrong order
Hi –hoping we have some good tips out there!
I have encountered an issue with ggplot's overlaid bar chart, only when two values are the same. I have three columns of data, for yesterday, three day and month that I am displaying on a horizontal bar chart where each column of data is a different color bar (yesterday = indianred2, three day = royalblue2, month = gray78). Using scale_fill_manual() (line 54) I have designated the order of the bars displayed; that is yesterday on top (indianred2), three day in the middle (royalblue2), and month (gray78) underneath. Additionally, the All_Rain_melt data set being used to fill the chart is ordered similarly, where yesterdays data is at the top of the data table, three day is in the middle, and month is at the bottom of the data table (see added snip below). The trouble is, when yesterday and three day values are the same number, the blue bar in the chart appears to be displaying over the red bar. I need yesterdays value, or the red bar to be on top of the blue bar. I know the red bar is present, because when I switch position = "identity" to position = "dodge" I see both the red and blue bars. I am unsure why this is occuring, and appears I have overlooked something. I would be grateful for suggestions on how to amend this.
Thank you!!

RainPlot<-ggplot(data=arrange(All_Rain_melt,-value))+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=125,xmax=95.25,ymin=0,ymax=ymax), alpha = 0.01, fill="darkseagreen1")+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=95.25,xmax=42.25,ymin=0,ymax=ymax), alpha = 0.01, fill="pink")+
  geom_rect(aes(xmin=42.25,xmax=0,ymin=0,ymax=ymax), alpha = 0.01, fill="moccasin")+
  geom_bar(aes(x=factor(new_row_no), y=value, width=0.6, fill=variable),stat="identity", position = "dodge")+coord_flip()+ 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("indianred2","royalblue2","gray78"))+
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0), breaks = seq(0,ymax,by=0.5),limits = c(0,ymax),sec.axis = dup_axis())+
  scale_x_discrete(breaks=RainLabels$new_row_no,
                   labels=RainLabels$station_name)+
  theme(legend.position = "top", legend.key.height = unit(0.5,"cm"), legend.key.width = unit(2,"cm"),legend.title = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major.x = element_line(color = "black", size = 0.5), panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "white"),
        axis.line = element_line(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=5, color="black"),axis.title = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(size=5, color="black"))+
  geom_label(aes(108, (2*ymax-2.5)/2,label = 'Northern'),label.size = NA, fill=NA)+
  geom_label(aes(69, (2*ymax-2.5)/2,label = 'Central'),label.size = NA, fill=NA)+
  geom_label(aes(18, (2*ymax-2.5)/2,label = 'Southern'),label.size = NA, fill=NA)+ 
  geom_vline(xintercept=95.5, color="black", linetype="dashed")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=42.5, color="black", linetype="dashed")


Welcome to SO! Unfortunately we can't run code based on images of data. If you need help then please provide a minimal reproducible example including a snippet of your input data best shared using dput() or using some fake data.
